# Storing multiple values from a table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to use

```
select * into <variable> from <table_name>
```

inside a stored procedure (pl/sql).

What should be type of `<variable>` to keep the multiple columns returned from 'table_name'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
table_name%RowType
```

Comment: How to obtain individual values?